# Getting google analytics data per user

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm looking to get information about users sessions from google analytics. Things like:

- date of visit
- referral
- device type
- exit page
- browser
- time on site
- etc.

However, Analytics API seems to only offer this data as totals, and not per user. So I can't know how much a specific user stayed on the website for example.

The final result I'm looking for is to tie this data from analytics with the user id from our CRM platform using the google UUID saved in cookie.

Is it possible to retrieve this data from Analytics or you can only access it with Analytics 360?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User level data is not available in standard GA (except in a limited fashion via the User Explorer report which cannot be exported). You'd need to store user id or client id in a custom dimension (you must not store personally identifiable data in GA, even in hashed form, so  take care what you use as user id) and then select this as first dimension when you export the data. Obviously this does not help you with data that's already been collected.